# Missing os-release file on GCP container vulnerability scan

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I am using GCP to host a flask app (deployed from Google SDK using `Gcloud app deploy`). I have enabled the vulnerability scanning in the Artifact Registry.

I navigate to the app-engine-tmp/build-cache/default/ttl-7d folder and under the latest built it says None found for vulnerabilities, but has  warning icon. Upon clicking it says:

Warning: The vulnerability list may not be complete because some scans have errored or are unsupported.
Errors:
Missing os-release file.

How do I rectify the missing os-release file?

Comment: Can you provide more details like images or commands or documentation that you follow? Have you checked this link on [scanning images for OS vulnerabilities automatically](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-analysis/docs/os-scanning-automatically)? Please check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LNo5.png) as reference.